# Reading PEM-formatted RSA keyfile with the OpenSSL C API

Tags: c, cryptography, openssl

I am trying to read in an AES-128-CBC encrypted PEM key file generated using Ruby with the OpenSSL API. The code that generated the PEM key is the following:

```
OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(2048).to_pem(OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new('128-CBC'), "password")
```

Here's the code that reads the PEM file:

```
RSA *rsa;

BIO *pem = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
BIO_puts(pem, "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
  "Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED\n"
  "DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,BB13D39833DD6ED1FF9843644E7981EE\n\n
  "Eugt8JZNKQKErsabWkwfm3wQhU/Tmp9T0QaP5HM8VIWpZwKlDmRlSUDptADU6RPD\n"
  "5VtG3DPieXcf+6deyARImid9sBBmQ9mK2omkNRcTMemqTOhAuaKBu78TMt9G4YSf\n"
  "RjoXWSqu3jMwrlcGkpn7bIum8wImITRZ3p28oSzk9aDUNBrIU/2Si8DM4RYIZ/fK\n"
  "Uvvgdok9dgcd0SjvucivX2HaGeg/IUz23q1jg9inDpimZvFJD1FJfGEUWDgyfJfa\n"
  "M8JIxTKbWOPEopONDkT7u4dC5VcSjK29MVbfd7iCKFPMh5UN+c96rPxTng/OWyW5\n"
  "0tvzHyyyvAG9p0Hx5Lr4pDbv21GHyu43sA6wbs9jWyqO3AB7CaoEEQhumwfLsdjj\n"
  "YGrX6bWThpYv/XNBDmmvltHlKFfe01NCybivOb4KwBnvi45x21PBqaZCKDTFdEkL\n"
  "iwDMTiG2iTxSUvPFLy30VFozE+pGyMcGDUyZDVqjsaqI/MRj8khnn5nyubXc27G3\n"
  "8Kbsnlix2SW2M0VDxqiy9dyjcxXrkFRSnOFYVs1PFlgjFVTG4Mwh6CZxKw8mFVbi\n"
  "EmLvUYwzoDZ1ve4VXSPp/vrKEh33JuHhM0vJOpqI6wqw0QR0I2o6etM1ZRJClPcw\n"
  "VIcgcvwenEgLOkoHDqOr0IZQAtYWvAuqq822wKt258hc6z8+ALQf5iMroqk7ADd4\n"
  "FlRLz4XTwqlg7pPtTde/emI1DT8dQWzq++QI0lr0CS/N1GXJKqTQDvauXLIiI3Qy\n"
  "KfFYFpV9jyYfRfTjNtisI/edPtp98auK0mb9o/wS/hruFI9behgv63iW1IwAOXCW\n"
  "ZlkWgobUH13gS864rL+AcrAXreo2j4dDQouTeRaJUEG0HoYTP65Zun/VsCi2aSOH\n"
  "JwSnnmHz9OxvcGY80WJDN3kqOCBRIJoDKBv6jcOxGVCsVK+WSdGZ7cfb8lwp7aA8\n"
  "8ND1bwL9FYkwkeIsoakj91iinqv4o3+3PUPgCU5oe68WYvAFjuU+criyf+EhmXJV\n"
  "JQ1vFFZPrGzgntJz19uXXh1h2iwQPggRouJm2RozYwvv1nz4eQ40Y3eT1F9UOYJU\n"
  "CKEhOtI2NpLeVOayqo8g9wO2oC+CQVhZhdYBE5o7pM7akFnYLvRg9s1UsWdcvT0G\n"
  "IpFmejLSRJ/F954aQMHTUc6vBOJZH/VNC5Qt+ulFXl634Sr9wQQK2qlqSJyA04TR\n"
  "1ixbCNOX71esvpFImsrlsO5oTA22T3h2GyJPUM10XhqGtDXtsTnal6smLna9U9B3\n"
  "gTVxFWWukQOF5Lm8ZFQipo2loHWjkozTBc4REPYP44SoXJXstv7k4pt1cK7x6/2H\n"
  "ElspXzjveqMhcrveWv1KaA2OGd+hGfUiNsCoIdapJjLz1Bd/+oIQ/ZWQeo0nRowE\n"
  "R/HlbbED3V+fRIdJpgydFEAw6gK5E9sYJcgF7uf/n2NabFxxEZL3g6MJQ64Dtusg\n"
  "DEH/MpvIYDSX4Navh1gTwCtOeG1CzW3diYaqbZK+UZCBLFU7j27YvVPSd6F2+Wud\n"
  "WnAqU3S5BCPqk5OD3wqZv+sEcqJgGPGy1Gv0tl8ARJomdKAru03KsRn2eIWqR5/C\n"
  "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n");

// Retrieve RSA key from PEM file.
rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(pem, NULL, pem_password_callback, "password");
```

And here's a dummy password callback (not sure about this function's purpose, but I think it may return the length of the password):

```
int pem_password_callback(char *buf, int max_len, int flag, void *pwd)
{
  return 8;
}
```

Currently, the `rsa = ...` part does not throw an error, but doesn't return a well-formed result either.

Comment: How do you know that is not well formed?

Comment: It does not seem that you are using opposite functions within the OpenSSL libraries. That is asking for trouble, especially since OpenSSL is not that well documented. E.g. it sometimes uses specific key derivation methods. Try to match up the encryption and decryption methods first (e.g. log what OpenSSL functions are called from Ruby, then reverse them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And here's a dummy password callback (not sure about this function's
>   purpose, but I think it may return the length of the password):
>
> ```
>  int pem_password_callback(char *buf, int max_len, int flag, void *pwd)
>  {
>      return 8;
>  }
> ```

No, its not a dummy. In your example, you just returned a buffer with 8 junk characters (whatever happened to be in `buf`).

The password callback is where you programmatically plug in your password. You are supplied with a `buff` of `max_len`, and you need to copy the password into the buffer and return the number of bytes copied.

```
int pem_password_callback(char *buf, int max_len, int flag, void *ctx)
{
    const char* PASSWD = "password";
    int len = strlen(PASSWD);

    if(len > max_len)
        return 0;

    memcpy(buf, PASSWD, len);
    return len;
}
```

The `flag` is a read/write flag to denote if you are reading a key or writing a key. In practice, I have never used it.

You will use it similar to:

```
FILE* file = ...;
EVP_PKEY* pkey = PEM_read_PrivateKey(file, NULL, pem_password_callback, NULL);
```

Unlike the write routine (which needs an `EVP_*` cipher), the read routine knows what you used to encrypt the key with because its encoded in the private key.

In my systems, I actually use the context for a label to ensure the same passwords arrive at different derived keys:

```
EVP_PKEY* pkey = PEM_read_PrivateKey(file, NULL, pem_password_callback, "Some Context");
```

Then, in my password callback:

```
int pem_password_callback(char *buf, int max_len, int flag, void *ctx)
{
    // "Some Context" in the example above
    char* label = (char*)ctx;

    // Hash password and label
    // ...

    // Copy hash to buffer, return length
    ...
}
```